# Doesn't using directives work with c++20 concepts?

Tags: c++, generic-programming, c++20, c++-concepts

Does using directives not work with concepts? why?

The example below doesn't work and I get a compiler error saying that it expected a type.

```cpp
#include <concepts>

namespace A::X {

  struct BaseA {};

  template < typename AType >
    concept DerivedFromA = std::derived_from < AType, BaseA >;

}

namespace A {

  using DerivedFromA = X::DerivedFromA;

}
```

I want to be able to access concept `DerivedFromA` from namespace `A` as `DerivedFromA` rather than `X::DerivedFromA`

Comment: Can you post the exact error from the compiler, including the line number and any other information that is necessary??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? `using` might not be the appropriate feature to use.

Comment: I want to be able to access the concept `DerivedFromA` from the namespace A as just `DerivedFromA` rather than doing `X:: DerivedFromA` @cigien

Comment: Concept is not a type. It makes sense not to be able to use `using` here.

Comment: Yes. It would be nice if there was a convenient way to achieve this though maybe using some other method, as concepts can still be considered as types right at a higher semantic level (not for the compiler though). @IllidanS4wantsMonicaback

Comment: Concepts are like predicates for types, but with some extra utility in determining when one concept is strictly more limiting than another (e.g., `random_access_iterator` is strictly more limiting than `forward_iterator`). That makes them closer to functions (limited to returning bool) than types. In fact, you used to be able to spell them as `concept bool Foo() { return ... }` before standardization.

Comment: Terminology note: A _using-directive_ is `using namespace N;` which is not what you're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does using directives not work with concepts? why?

Because the way you're employing `using` declares a type alias. And `concept`s are not type templates.

What you *intend* to do is to make a name from one namespace available in a different one. That looks like this:

```
namespace A
{
  using X::DerivedFromA;
}
```

This works on all kinds of names.